# url_for generates a url with current path inserted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am generating a url in my controller accessed from the relative path "/hangouts/test", for a url on an external site (facebook). I want to use url_for and pass in params using hashes so it can escape them. The URL I want is this:

http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php?api_key=6aca22e72866c7eaaedfb15be69c4b93&...

Using this, however:

```
url_for(:host => "www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php?", :api_key => Facebooker.api_key, :next => test_hangouts_url, :cancel => root_url, :ext_perm  => "publish_stream")
```

I instead get my current path of /hangouts/test thrown in there:

http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php**/hangouts/test**?api_key=6aca22e72866c7eaaedfb15be69c4b93&...

As you can see, I don't want "/hangouts/test" to be in there - played a bit with the options in the API docs but stumped, anybody know how to use url_for without it inserting the current path? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the hash form of url_for to generate links outside of your application.

Instead you should just be using the string version form:

```
url_for "http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php?api_key=6aca22e72866c7eaaedfb15be69c4b93&next=#{test_hangouts_url}&cancel=#{root_url}&ext_perm=publish_stream"
```

url_for will use the current action controller/action/id unless the hash given to url_for contains one of those arguments. url_for will then generate a url from a route that matches the arguments given in the hash. The arguments to url_for used in the question generates a valid url, because it can match a route using the current controller/action. You will not be able to generate the url you want with the hash form of url for without matching a route. Providing a controller in the hash you give url_for should match the default routes that rails generates for you when you create an application, but that's not very DRY.

The better solution is to use a named route:

```
map.prompt_fb_permissions "/connect/prompt_permissions.php", 
  :host => "www.facebook.com", :controller => nil, :action => nil
```

then you can use the following in place of url_for whenever you want to generate this this url.

```
prompt_fb_permissions(:api_key => Facebooker.api_key, :next => test_hangouts_url, 
  :cancel => root_url, :ext_perm  => "publish_stream")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, EmFi - I did not know that url_for needed to generate based on matching a route; I had wanted to pass in hashes to be "more elegant" than the string :)

Answer (score 0):

You left out the `controller` parameter, which is why it's automatically adding your controller path ("/hangouts/test"), to your base host.

Try this:

```
url_for(:host => "www.facebook.com", :controller=> "/connect/prompt_permissions.php", :api_key => Facebooker.api_key, :next => test_hangouts_url, :cancel => root_url, :ext_perm  => "publish_stream")
```